# Resolving 'Could not load type' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to fix this error for hours and hours, I tried everything I could do so with no success. I am realitvely new to C#. I was wondering if someone can help me identify how I can begin to resolve this error?

Error Message:

```
Could not load type 'Inventory1.Global'.    W:\admin.fctl.ucf.edu\inventory\Global.asax 1
```

Global.asax Contents:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Inventory1.Global" Language="C#"%>
```

Global.asax.cs Contents:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace Inventory1 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Global.
    /// </summary>
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        public Global()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   

        protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region Web Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {    
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: MiGusta, is this code that you are trying to fix on a remote server or on you local machine.. also is there a `W:\` drive on your the machine where you are trying to run / debug this ..have you even debugged the code..? or are you just doing a code and run type of scenario..?

Comment: Remote server. I am in the process of debugging. What I am trying to do is rebuild the `Inventory` project in visual Studio and create a new .dll file because the old application has been down for days. So I need to debug this code in order to rebuild, which is what I have been trying to do for some time now. The error above is the only error I have been getting.

Comment: So where is this running from (while you're trying to debug), your local machine?

Comment: well sounds like you need to either map a drive to that location from where you are debugging it or if the path is hard coded you need to change it you point to a directory that's on that remote machine.. can you try getting to that drive by doing the following from Windows Explorer `\\W:\admin.fctl.ucf.edu\inventory`

Comment: I cannot access the drive in that way.

Answer (score 0):

That code works on my machine.  Check to make sure the Dll exists in the /bin directory.  Also, make sure that the bin and Global.asax file exist in the root of the application.  It is quite possible that somebody at the server level changed something in IIS.

Comment: Josh by `Changed something in IIS` do you mean the Virtual Dir Path in regards to the OP..?

Comment: The old .dll is faulty/outdated and causing the application to crash. I am trying to create a new one be rebuilding the Inventory project, what would be a good way of troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - yup.  Sometimes the path gets changed without devs knowing it and then they aren't really working in the root directory anymore.